# Changing mysql table comment

Tags: mysql, table, comments

I know that mysql **table comment** can be defined at the creation with:

`create table (...)comment='table_comment';`

And you can display comments by:

`show table status where name='table_name';`

How do you change (alter?) *table comment* after it's been created. I mean wihtout dropping and recreating the table again.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_comments;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

CREATE TABLE test_comments (ID INT, name CHAR(30)) COMMENT 'Hello World';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)
```

**Check you comments in table structure**

```
show create table test_comments\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test_comments
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_comments` (
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` char(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Hello World'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**You can also check comments from information_schema like below**

```
SELECT TABLE_COMMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test_comments';
+---------------+
| TABLE_COMMENT |
+---------------+
| Hello World   |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Alter table to modify comments**

```
ALTER TABLE test_comments COMMENT = 'This is just to test how to alter comments';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Check the modified comments**

```
show create table test_comments\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test_comments
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test_comments` (
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` char(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='This is just to test how to alter comments'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT TABLE_COMMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test_comments';
+--------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_COMMENT                              |
+--------------------------------------------+
| This is just to test how to alter comments |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Bonus question: would it be safe to directly modify `column_comment` from `information_schema.columns`  (since the `alter table ...` requires to specify all the column definition, again) ?

Comment: @e2-e4 , the `information_schema` tables are actually read-only views. You can't modify them directly. But good question!