# How to store values that include numbers and strings? Example: 1.25, trace, not applicable, etc

Tags: database-design, datatypes, mysql-8.0

I created a database for nutritional table information. This database have values like carbohydrates, protein and fats of a food (there is a total of 28 fields).

The problem is that there are special cases where these values can be strings:

- if the amount of a nutrient in the food is too small, the value will be
  "Tr" (trace).
- If the measurement does not apply to that food, the value will be "NA"

and some other cases.

I am currently using strings to store the values, and converting them to numbers in my app. But there is a better way to do this?

Here is a example of what the table looks like:

```
id, kilocalories, carbohydrate_grams, lipid_grams, protein_grams

'1', '123.5348925', '25.80975', 'Tr', 'NA'
```

I am using MySQL 8.

Sorry, i think you needed a bit more of information.

I let NULL enabled, but there is no case that the field should be null. I just enabled it because this database can receive new data later, with other conventions. (I am using the brazilian database of foods, but I will insert the american database in the future).

Any field in the table can receive one of these values:

- * means that the tests are being re-evaluated;
- Empty fields means that no lab test was requested to that field;
- NA means not applicable;
- Tr means trace;

This is a dump of the real table with two lines of data:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `nutritional_table`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nutritional_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `nutritional_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kilocalories` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `carbohydrate_grams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lipid_grams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saturados` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monoinsaturados` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `poliinsaturados` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protein_grams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dietary_fiber_grams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ashes_grams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cholesterol_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calcium_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `magnesium_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manganese_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phosphorus_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iron_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sodium_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `potassium_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `copper_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zinc_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thiamine_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `riboflavin_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pyridoxine_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `niacin_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vitamin_c_milligrams` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `retinol_micrograms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RE_micrograms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RAE_micrograms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=598 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `nutritional_table`
--

LOCK TABLES `nutritional_table` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `nutritional_table` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `nutritional_table` VALUES
(1,'123.5348925','25.80975','1.000333333','0.3','0.4','0.3','2.58825','2.749333333','0.463','NA','5.204','58.702','0.627333333','105.853','0.262','1.244666667','75.15166667','0.020333333','0.682666667','0.08','Tr','0.08','Tr','','NA','',''),
(2,'359.678002','77.45071413','1.864833333','0.3','0.5','0.4','7.32328587','4.819166667','1.181333333','NA','7.818','109.71','2.993333333','250.865','0.948333333','1.645666667','173.34','0.074833333','1.395166667','0.261666667','Tr','0.175','4.183333333','','NA','','');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `nutritional_table` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

saturados, monoinsaturados and poliinsaturados are the same as the other fields. I had to translate this to english (they are written in portuguese) and add the suffix _milligrams to them. I just let to do fix this later.

About the abbreviations: I used the full names because I think it is more easily readable. I get a little confused with the abbreviations. But in the app I am showing the data using the abbreviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Store the numbers as numbers! For 'Trace', 'N/A' &c. have negative integers as codes and deal with the logic that way - `CASE` and company! **OR**, use `GENERATED` fields and let the server do all the conversions from `VARCHAR` to `INT` - never have to worry about a mistake again! Check out the use of a `CASE`statement in a `GENERATED` column definition at the bottom of this answer!

I would do this in one of two ways:

## First way (the better of the two - by far!):

You have:

```
CREATE TABLE nutritional_table 
(
  ..
  ..
  carbohydrate_grams varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

The gramme/gram is an SI unit: [SI unit symbol: g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram)

Anything with gramme/gram should be a pure number. The field/column containing it should be suffixed with `_g`.

Just as a matter of interest, should that not be `... (255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`? It beats the `COALESCE` function - I always to try and avoid `NULL`s **if possible**!

```
monoinsaturados varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
poliinsaturados varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Are these all numbers or percentages or what? If pure numbers or %, then store them as pure numbers, or with `_pc` as a percent suffix.

```
cholesterol_milligrams varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

> one-millionth of a kilogram is 1 mg (one milligram),

The milligramme is a recognised unit, [albeit not official SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram#SI_multiples). The suffix should be `_mg`!

> The microgram is typically abbreviated "mcg" in pharmaceutical and nutritional supplement labelling, to avoid confusion, since the "μ" prefix is not always well recognised outside of technical disciplines

All microgram units should be suffixed with `_mcg`.

```
retinol_micrograms varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=598 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Why you go to the trouble of converting the units back and forth as strings is beyond me!

You should also maintain `comment`s on your tables so that poor devs don't get confused and have no excuse for f**ing up! Make it part of SOP that when a field is added, an explanatory comment is added. Also, the tables themselves should have comments, possibly with references about where to find further information (example - of use later on!).

```
CREATE TABLE nutritional_content 
(
  nutrient_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY comment 'The Primary Key - doh!!!',
  test_measurement_gr VARCHAR (255) comment 'The weight of M&Ms in Outer Space'
) comment 'This table contains units of measurement as outlined in https://your_server/tables/nutritional_content.html';
```

Then, one can do stuff like this (table comments):

```
-- Learnt lots about comments on tables and columns - useful stuff!
-- Check out these links - upvote if you're feeling generous - I was!

-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404051/show-comment-of-fields-from-mysql-table/5404118
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938966/how-can-i-access-the-table-comment-from-a-mysql-table
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns
-- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59587/changing-mysql-table-comment

SELECT table_comment 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
--    WHERE table_schema='my_cool_database' -- fiddle - don't know schema_name
      WHERE table_name = 'nutritional_content ';
```

Result:

```
TABLE_COMMENT
This table contains units of measurement as outlined in https://your_server/tables/nutritional_content.html
```

Field comments:

```
SELECT column_name, column_type, column_default, column_comment
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name =  'nutritional_content'
-- and `table_schema` = 'db-name'; -- fiddle - don't know schema_name
```

Result:

```
COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_TYPE COLUMN_DEFAULT  COLUMN_COMMENT
nutrient_id int(11)     The Primary Key - doh!!!
test_measurement_gr varchar(255)        The weight of M&Ms in Outer Space in grammes
```

Note the explanation of what units are being used, in case anybody is so slow that they don't realise that the `_gr` suffix is grammes!

For `Trace`, 'N/A' &c. - have a code table, say:

```
CREATE TABLE nutrition_code
(
  code_id SIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY (CHECK the_code < 0)
  the_code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO nutrition_code VALUES (-1, 'Trace'), (-2, 'N/A');
```

So, I would imagine that **most of the time**, you're not too interested in traces or not-applicables? This might introduce a level of complexity, but I still think that it's a win-win compared to your current scenario. Take a look at the bottom of the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6ff1d18b64f4e0d5ddd8d8fe2d3a1f8) for how to `CAST`these - **very** hacky - but then it is MySQL! :-)

OK, so far, so good - **if** you want to overhaul your system, which I advise you to at least set as a long term goal, but better to start ASAP!

But, what you can do - if, say, for legacy reasons you have to keep your table the way it is while you change to a reasonable table structure is this!

## The second way (temporary until code refactoring):

This would be to use [`GENERATED`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) (or `COMPUTED` or sometimes called `VIRTUAL`) columns (although `VIRTUAL` is a misnomer as they may - in the case of MySQL such fields can be either `VIRTUAL`or `STORED`(aka `PERSISTENT`)). As an aside, this is one of the **very few** ways in which MySQL is actually superior to PostgreSQL which can only have `STORED` (i.e. materialised) `GENERATED` columns for the moment, though I would always recommend PostgreSQL in preference to MySQL (personal opinion!).

What I would recommend then (as a temporary solution) is something like this (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6ff1d18b64f4e0d5ddd8d8fe2d3a1f8) - all the SQL above is also included in the fiddle):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), the syntax is:

```
col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expr)
  [VIRTUAL | STORED] [NOT NULL | NULL]
  [UNIQUE [KEY]] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
```

To implement this, I had to `CAST` the `VARCHAR(255)` field to an `INTEGER`. I **EVENTUALLY** found the following solutions (how do you do it?):

```
-- This took me effing ages!

SELECT   CAST(test_measurement_gr               AS UNSIGNED) AS mes_num FROM nutritional_content;
SELECT      (`test_measurement_gr` * 1)         AS mes_num FROM nutritional_content;
SELECT      (`test_measurement_gr` + 0) + 1000  AS mes_num FROM nutritional_content;
SELECT SQRT((`test_measurement_gr` + 0) + 1000) AS mes_num FROM nutritional_content;

-- **Completely** Fu*ked if I kndw why MySQL does it this way, but c'est la vie!
-- Check out the links to the manuals in the link here:
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql
```

Result (1st and last SQL statements only):

The `SQRT()` function proves that it's acting as a proper number!

```
mes_num
     10
     12
     26
```

and

```
mes_num
31.78049716414141
31.811947441173732
32.03123475609393
```

So, now I'm ready to create my table with generated fields:

```
CREATE TABLE nutritional_content_bis 
(
  nutrient_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY comment 'The Primary Key - doh!!!',
  test_measurement_gr VARCHAR (255) comment 'The weight of M&Ms in Outer Space',
  test_measurement_gr_num INTEGER 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(test_measurement_gr AS UNSIGNED)) VIRTUAL  -- or STORED on disk
) comment 'This table contains units of measurement as outlined in https://your_server/tables/nutritional_content.html';

-- you can have it as persistent if you wish to avoid excessive calculations,
-- but you're doing these anyway. Tradeoff between CPU/RAM and HDD space!
```

Poplulate it:

```
INSERT INTO nutritional_content (test_measurement_gr)
VALUES
('10'), ('12'), ('26');
```

Then check (always check!):

```
SELECT 
  nutrient_id AS n_id,
  test_measurement_gr AS grammes_txt,
  test_measurement_gr_num AS gramme_num -- Just like any normal field!
FROM nutritional_content_bis;
```

Result:

```
n_id    grammes_txt gramme_num
   1    10          10
   2    12          12
   3    26          26
```

And a double check of our new numeric field (`ROUND()` and `SQRT()`):

```
-- To prove that they're really numbers!
SELECT ROUND(SQRT(test_measurement_gr_num), 2) AS num_test FROM nutritional_content_bis;
```

Result:

```
num_test
3.16
3.46
5.10
```

In addition to greatly simplifying your life, this approach should also be more performant. I would suggest that you perhaps try and do some tests on the different tables and see what you come up with.

For example, if you  are asked to get the average positive ion content from Group 1 of the Periodic Table, you just have to add the Na and K content - with your current approach, you have get your raw data, convert it to a number, add it and obtain your result. A lot of work for nothing.

## EDIT: - in response to comments beginning [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254383/how-to-store-values-that-include-numbers-and-strings-example-1-25-trace-not/254403?noredirect=1#comment501592_254403).

`saturados, monoinsaturados and poliinsaturados` - Saturates (or saturated_fat), monounsaturates and polyunsaturates.

`About the abbreviations you mentioned, like _g instead of grams, i used the full names because i think it is more easily readable. I get a little confused with the abbreviations.`

This is why I placed stress on **using** table and field comments in your particular case.

`I would like to upvote, but i cant do this yet`

Your vote will be recorded and applied when you have sufficient reputation - I'll help - your question was interesting and provided a challenge, so +1!

`I do not "feel so good" in using a value that should be the amount of that nutrient as a flag if it is negative`

Neither do I "feel so good" about this particular solution, but it's probably the lesser of two evils - the other way of tackling this problem is to use the [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) [anti-pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=eav%20antipattern&oq=eav%20anti&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l6.2111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which opens a whole other can of worms! I've also [written about it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007%20EAV). EAV to a dev/progammer, is like heroin to a drug addict - things start great, then they spiral out of control until the situation is a complete mess. I always put this image into my mind if ever I'm tempted to use it, even for a "small" (they always grow) configuration table.

[image]

`About the GENERATED fields, this way i will just lose the information of the special cases not? So it defeats the purpose of using strings at the first place. But, as you said, this is to be used as a temporary solution.`

Maybe not so temporary? I didn't know this was possible, but you can do stuff like this (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3aab000c1ae882a0fb42b95d3c9b7e06) - really thrilled I got this to work!!! - definitely a +1 for the question):

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  v1 VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  v2 INTEGER       NOT NULL,
  v3 INTEGER 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (
      CASE 
        WHEN v1 = 'Tr' THEN -1
        WHEN v1 = 'N/A' THEN -2  -- can add more - e.g. 'unknown', 'don''t care'...
        ELSE CAST(v1 AS UNSIGNED)
      END
    ) CHECK (v3 > -10 AND v3 < 100000) COMMENT 'The values "Tr" and "N/A" come from table_name...'
) COMMENT 'This table structure rocks!';
```

Then, perform some inserts:

```
INSERT INTO foo (v1, v2) VALUES ('123', 1), ('256', 2), ('Tr', -1), ('N/A', -2);
```

Check:

```
SELECT 
  v1, 
  v2, 
  v3, 
  ROUND(COALESCE(SQRT(v3), 0), 2) AS sqrt_neg, -- showing off! 
  ROUND(SQRT(ABS(v3)), 2) AS check_num
FROM foo;
```

Result:

```
v1  v2   v3 sqrt_neg    check_num
123  1  123    11.09        11.09
256  2  256    16.00        16.00
Tr  -1   -1     0.00         1.00
N/A -2   -2     0.00         1.41
```

So, with the `CASE` [expression](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/) and the [`CHECK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) constraint (introduced in MySQL 8.0.16 - a mere 30 years after every other major database server had them!), you have reasonably fine-grained control over what goes into that field!

The only fly in the ointment is that your devs/programmers will have to remember to put the correct field values into the `CASE` statement - but, I think this is easier than your current situation (IMNSHO) - or using EAV! However, the upside is that it **ONLY** has to be done correctly **ONCE** - in the table definition - get that right and you never have to worry about inconsistent data again!

Finally, the icing on the cake:

```
INSERT INTO foo (v1, v2) VALUES ('shit', 45);
```

Result:

```
Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'shit'
```

So, only those strings which are meaningful will be allowed to be `INSERT`ed into your field! In theory, if SQL was allowed in `CHECK` constraints, you would have even more control over your data. It's a pity that MySQL (and nobody else apart from Firebird) allows them, but they're probably on the way - but, hey, it only took MySQL 30 years to implement `CHECK` constraints so who knows?...

Comment: "Just as a matter of interest, should that not be ... (255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0? It beats the COALESCE function - I always to try and avoid NULLs if possible!"

Yes! You are right. I did not set a default value because the data of this table is not dynamic, so i just take a full database and make a batch job to insert the rows. But i will have to do as you mentioned, because later i will add a function to enable dynamic inserts in the table, using user inputs.

Comment: @Vérace (@Michael Wallace): Using values off the actual data range for a given attribute - so called magic values - runs the risk of calculations returning unexpected results. (Yes: You can filter for these. But you must do this all the time…) From my perspective, you replace one potential trouble maker by a different one.

Comment: @Vérace: I like the New Cuyama picture! ;-) And having the (poor) guy having to maintain it in mind, I tend to keep things apart. (Didn't elaborate on whether ontologically different things should be stored in the same column…) I had in the past fun in pulling things together in an EAV challenged database schema. (And to get the queries run fast…) Not sure, why you prefer to generate the magic values. The application will have to handle them one way or the other… (Did you mean to actually use the **v2** column for something?)

Comment: v2 was just there to show that everything else worked OK, not essential for the demo - aversion to one-field tables. New Cuyama is great!  `Not sure, why you prefer to generate the magic values` - `GENERATED` because the OP will want to perform `SUM()`s on `INTEGER`s (or `FLOAT`s or whatever), add the number of mg of Group 1 elements of the Periodic Table (Na + K), then numbers are required. No reliance on non-standard behaviour. In MySQL, this works `SELECT SQRT('49');` - WTF? Should the OP ever wish to port to a real db (i.e. PostgreSQL :-) ), it'll be good to have code that works anywhwere!

Comment: `Should the OP ever wish to port to a real db (i.e. PostgreSQL :-) )` - though I have to say that MySQL 8 is a real stride forward for the server - `CTE`s, Window functions, `CHECK` constraints, `GENERATED` columns - it's putting it up to PostgreSQL, although the latter is still streets ahead. Pg's downside - no `VIRTUAL` columns, no `UNSIGNED` ints (any others you can think of?) - but these are minor niggles compared to MySQL's gotchas!

Comment: I will also give a try to this solution with GENERATED fields. But i am more likely to use the negative numbers, since they are so killing simple and portable to any database (I made my backend with PHP + MySQL 8 because this stack is very cheap to host anywhere. But if the app grows i can need to migrate to something else).

Comment: About @Abecee comment on the risk of using these values on calculations, you can simply do a "where x > 0". Since is impossible to exist a negative weight measurement there is no way to mix these information.

Comment: About using EAV, well, i had think about this when started to model my database. But this would create a hell on hearth to deal with my data! My table now have 656 records. With EAV i would end-up with +18.000 records! And, in the end, i will have to send this information in a JSON to the front-end, so i will just end-up remaking the same 28 fields again haha

Comment: If you're working with JSON, then I would definitely recommend that you move to PostgreSQL - its JSON capabilities far outstrip in this area **far** outstrip those of MySQL (this is **not** an opinion - check it out for yourself!).

Comment: @Vérace: Having potential calculations in mind, I'd save everybody (OP and everybody else having to work with it later on) from having to filter the negative values. So, if OP prefers to dump all data into one column, I'd generate one, which has only actual numbers and **NULL** instead of any strings. This way, the original column is ready for display, the generated one for calculations (with no filtering at all).

Comment: @MichaelWallace: My concern is: Of course everybody "can" == "will be able" to filter out the negative values. However: If somebody forgets (or -being misinformed or ignorant or …- simply ignores) the need to filter, the result is rubbish. In other words: One "must" rather than "can"…

Comment: Yes, you are right @Abecee. This is a real concern and can create problems in many situations: mainly due communication issues in the team. I myself already worked with crypt databases full of edge cases like this. But i think this is not a problem in this scenario. I am working in this project alone by now. And if the project grow i will have to communicate this spec of the database by telling the people and by adding comments in the table, as mentioned.

Comment: Also, is someone forget to do this filtering the harm will not be big because the main fields (kilocalories, protein, fat and carbs) rarely have special cases like this. The other fields are useful information but are not so important in my scenario.

Now that you make me think about this, you have a good point. This can lead to many strange scenarios if someone forget to filter this (i myself can forget this haha). I will try to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

- You could, for the relevant columns, add another column each to hold potential string values and change the existing column to some number type. Whether or not that makes sense, does largely depend on your application. If you want to do calculations at the database layer (or right away at the application layer), actual numbers in the database would help.
- If **NULL**, **NA** and empty strings are in your context essentially the same, use **NULL** consistently.
- If **TR** is the only non-numeric value, switch, e.g., to

  `riboflavin_milligrams numeric DEFAULT NULL,
   riboflavin_milligrams_trace TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,`
- You could still return either a number (converted to a string) or **Tr**, if needed:

  `CASE riboflavin_milligrams_trace
     WHEN 1 THEN 'Tr'
     ELSE CAST(riboflavin_milligrams AS CHAR)
   END AS riboflavin`
- You might want to ensure one way or the other, there is no non-null value in the numeric column, if the trace column holds a **1** for **TRUE**…
- With the generated columns -thanks to @Vérace for the reminder- there is even the option to combine the string and numeric values already in the database for those cases, where the value is for display only:

  `riboflavin_milligrams_char varchar(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE riboflavin_milligrams_trace WHEN 1 THEN 'Tr' ELSE CAST(riboflavin_milligrams AS CHAR) END) VIRTUAL,`
- Given OP's preference for a single string column to store potential values for a particular attribute, a generated column could provide the resulting numbers (only - not added magic values):

  `riboflavin_milligrams varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  riboflavin_milligrams_number float GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONVERT (riboflavin_milligrams, float)) VIRTUAL,`

See it in action: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39c67dfd07dac52b5dbdf417d3072da1) (Using your script with some adjustments.)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: This. NULL is the proper way to handle N/A in SQL. Internally it is held as a flag separate from the actual data value. By extension, this is a suitable way to deal with other special case flags such as "trace".

Comment: So adding new fields to the current table is not viable, i will have to duplicate all the fields (winch i think is a bigger problem tan dealing with the numbers as text)

Comment: @MichaelWallace: (i) You seem to consider to mix data from different sources (Brazilian vs. American). I'd keep them apart in the database (adding another column to indicate the respective source) and combine them only when needed. Would, e.g., facilitate updates to your database when changes are applied at one of the sources. (ii) Not sure, why you can't change the current table - you seem to be in the driver's seat. But that's your call.

Comment: @MichaelWallace: (iii) Actually, I'd consider to add one more column each, borrowing Vérace's generated columns - in order to have a character column for display (only) rather than calculations.

Comment: @Abecee about mixing Brazilian and American information, i have other tables that track the food details and data sources. This tables is just to hold nutritional information (you can notice that there is no field with the name of the food here).

Comment: @Abecee I can create new fields without problem. I just think this way i will be adding a layer of complexity that maybe it is not necessary.  Lets think about it: My table has 28 fields: one for id, one for kilocalories (these fields do not have special cases) and all the other fields has special cases. So i will have to add a new fields for each one of these. My table now will have 54 fields, and i will have to replicate this structure in my backend and in the frontend.

Comment: In my app i will have to create a class to check each field and then check for the field special cases (by now i simply try to convert to a number, if it fails to convert is because it is a string). I also will have to split this information in these new fields, winch will require a lot of work to do everything correctly. So i do not see any advantage in creating a new field to handle this special cases, since it will just make things worse to work and will not add any advantage. I will also have to create queries with 26 joins every time i want to see this information in the same table.

Comment: @MichaelWallace: (i) I've seen different nutritional information for identical products… But… (ii) If you prefer a single string column only for storage, I'd at least generate a numeric column (with no magic values) for calculations… This way, the database (semantics) should shield you from unintended actions/effects.